# Svelte Library [Ckeditor 5] works as node module but not locally

Tags: ckeditor, svelte, ckeditor5, vite, sveltekit

I'm trying to add Ckeditor5 to Sveltekit.

Using the node module works perfectly. I import the library `onMount` and use it.

```html
// Works flawlessly
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let Editor;
  onMount(async () => {
    const module = await import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block');
    Editor = module.default;
    Editor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {}).then((editor) => {
      console.log(editor);
    });
  });
</script>
```

If I try to import a local build, however, `module.default` is always `undefined`. The same happens even when I just copy the node_module.

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let Editor;
  onMount(async () => {
    // Import changed to local build
    const module = await import('src/lib/ckeditor');
    Editor = module.default;
    Editor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {}).then((editor) => {
      console.log(editor);
    });
  });
</script>
```

It's also worth noting that logging the local module just prints:
`Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'}` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your /src/lib/ckeditor file contents?

Sidenote. when accessing DOM elements, you can do the folowing instead of using document.querySelector

```js
<script>
 let editorEl;
 onMount(()=>{
    Editor.create(editorEl, {})
 })
</script>

<div bind:this={editorEl}></div>
```

Comment: It's a single ckeditor.js file being imported. The behavior doesn't change even if I use a package structure.